# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker PHP application

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a docker container running on AWS EB on a t1.micro, which is a PHP application that loops through some tasks, sleeps for a few minutes, and loops through its tasks again. Tasks involve moving some data on an FTP, and updating records from a Redis store.

It always builds and runs fine, but after a day the health of the application changes to "Warning", the causes state that CPU is running at 100%, I don't see any activity on the FTP that it processes, and the logs show nothing indicating the application failing.

Is this just a case of upgrading the EC2 instance to a higher spec? Or is there a flaw in the way i'm running the container that would release resource after each iteration.

Thanks

Comment: It obviously thinks that CPU is at 100% for a reason. What do the CloudWatch metrics look like? Can you login to the server and run `top` to see what is happening?

Comment: it shows the CPU running as "normal", then shoot up to 100% and stay at that level around 5am.. I cant see anything in the logs that suggests anything going wrong around that time

Comment: So are you able to run something like `top` on the instance to see what is actually using the CPU?

Comment: ive made a change to the code to do some garbage collection. if it happens again, ill try this ^

Thanks for your help Mark